# Which GPUImage fillmode for fullscreen on all iPhone size?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I would like my GPUImageView (portrait, front camera) to be fullscreen whatever the phone screen size (from iPhone 4 to Iphone 6+). Ideally following an "Aspect fill" mode.

Right now I have :

```
   _vidCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc]
                  initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
                  cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    _vidCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

    // View
    CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    _filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:f];
```

Would kGPUImageFillModeStretch be enough ? Do I need to change the SessionPreset as well ? If I change the Session preset to something bigger than say the iPhone 4 can handle, will it cause trouble ?

Sorry I can't test it myself because I don't own more than an iPhone 4.

Comment: Thank you, you can make this an answer if you want.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 mode in the source code.

```
public var kGPUImageFillModeStretch: GPUImageFillModeType { get }
// Stretch to fill the full view, which may distort the image outside of its normal aspect ratio


public var kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio: GPUImageFillModeType { get } 
// Maintains the aspect ratio of the source image, adding bars of the specified background color


public var kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill: GPUImageFillModeType { get } 
// Maintains the aspect ratio of the source image, zooming in on its center to fill the view
```

In my opinion, It is better to use **kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill**. Using the stretch option causes weird outputs.

To set the fillMode to your GPUImageFilter:

```
filterView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill
```